# Need time (X) values to be static to match up with CPU values (Y)

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: updated chart][image: plot]

Flow is as follows:

`cpustats.txt` is a text tile that gets update every ~1 second with the time and CPU load.

`getcpustats.py` repeatedly opens `cpustats.txt` and plots the time (`x`) and the CPU load (`y`).

Current problems are the following:

1. I need to make the Y axis static (0 to 100) since the numbers currently jump around.
2. I need to make sure the CPU load matches the time (ex: at 08:05, the CPU load was ....)

For item one I attempted to make it static but then the chart failed to update.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#x = [0,100]
x = []
y = []

def animate(i):
    with open('cpustats.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
        list_of_lines = searchfile.read().splitlines()
        time = (list_of_lines[0])
        cpu_val = (list_of_lines[1])
        cpu_val = cpu_val[:-1]
        y.append(cpu_val)
        x.append(time)

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x,y)

    ax=plt.gca()
    plt.gca().get_xticklabels()
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)

    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('CPU Usage %')
    plt.title('Real time CPU usage of user\'s MBP')
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=5000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `plt.ylim([0, 100])` to `animate` fix the y limits from 0 to 100 as you say in (*1.*),

```py
def animate(i):
   # ...
   plt.ylim([0, 100])
   plt.xlabel('Time')
   # ...
```

But also note that the CPU usage can exceed 100% so you don't actually want 100 as the upper limit, usually you would want `100*nthreads` for the CPU.

You also need to convert the usage values (`cpu_val`) to floats before appending them,

```py
y.append(float(cpu_val))
```

Comment: William to the rescue once again! :-) Can you elaborate on "nthreads"? How is it defined?

Comment: That's just the number of threads the cpu has, e.g. for an AMD 2990WX Threadripper 2 there are 64 threads

Comment: `import multiprocessing; multiprocessing.cpu_count()` should get you the number of threads, though I'm not familiar with how it handles hyperthreading

Comment: Ok, thx. I'm now importing multiprocessing (multiprocessing.cpu_count does not exist). I'm also converting the cpu_val to float. However, now the chart is not updating. I'm suspecting my ani assignment. Updated image above.

Comment: It's `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` (with parentheses), works in Python 2.7 and 3.6

Comment: @wiwinut The only reason the chart wouldn't be updating with the code you have is if you are not plotting anything. Check that `x` and `y` are non-empty before `plt.plot(x, y)`

Comment: Once again you have come to my rescue! Thank you 1000x once again!

Comment: @wiwinut No problem, glad I could help